# How to filter the results of a query passing a string as a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to append the `mail_d_list` only if the flag is set in the model.

I am calling this function with the `airport_code` already coming in from the user. Now I would like to add the user to the email list  if they have the flag selected for the user or not.

Each user in the model has six boolean flags, one flag for each report possible. The text for the flag is in the middle.

I have tried `.get()` and `.filter()`

`Models.py`

```
class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    ''' Aerodrome model for storing three-letter airport codes iata,
    airport description and the database partition informtion. '''
    iata = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    partition_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class DistributionList(models.Model):
    ''' List of all email addresses that are to receive
    automated emails from the system '''
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    receive_emails = models.BooleanField()
    receives_report = models.ManyToManyField(Aerodrome)
```

`script.py`

```
for user in DistributionList.objects.filter(receives_report__iata=airport_code):
    mail_d_list.append(user.email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely the wrong approach.

You already have the aerodromes defined in a separate model. You should define a ManyToManyField as a relationship between them, rather than dynamically defining fields on your DistributionList model. Then your script can filter by that relationship.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I have created the ManyToManyField(), and added a couple of options for each user. I will now try and filter the result. Code above is updated. Thanks